# How can I mock only a function inside an component when tests are running in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a test where I render the whole App and then trying to login. The login is an component which I load into the App. There is a method called loginUser  which does the fetch request. How can I mock this function to return a stub of the response from the server? I only want to mock the loginUser function.

**Test:**

```js
beforeEach(() => {
    render(<App />)
})

test('should login', async () => {
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Username/i), { target: { value: 'speedrun.io' } })
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByPlaceholderText(/Password.../i), { target: { value: '1234' } })

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(/Sign in/i))
    const errorMessage = await screen.findByText(/Successful Login/i)
    expect(errorMessage).toHaveClass("success-feedback")
})
```

**Login:**

```
const Login = (props) => {
   
    const loginUser = async (credentials) => {
        // Fetch
    }
    const handleSubmit = async e => {
        const token = await loginUser({
            username,
            password
        })
        if (token.access_token) {
            // Do something
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Create React App.

Comment: You can' mock the `loginUser` function, it's defined in functional scope. It's private. You should mock `fetch` request

Comment: Good idea :) I'm going to try this.